# trying to understand the effect of flushing a buffer problem

Tags: c++, c++11, buffer

I'm a complete beginner in C++, so I'm deeply sorry if my question would sound stupid or something.

I have been reading a book that gave a simple intro about stream buffers, and in some cases it's important to flush the buffer, so to understand the effect I ran the following code:

code1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>   
using namespace std;
      
int main()
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
  {
      cout << i << " ";
      this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
  }
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

code2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
   {
      cout << i << " " << flush;
      this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Both codes give the same output, there is no difference at all, they print 1 sleeping for 1 second followed by 2, sleep for another second, and so on.

I have tried to run the codes in both DevC++ and CodeBlocks, which gave the same result.

The book says the result of code1 --> "the program waits for 5 seconds and prints all the numbers at once", and the result of code2 --> "the program prints the number waits for 1 second and prints the second number and so on".

I really don't understand what went wrong.

Comment: Try running the compiled non-`flush`ing program from the command line. If you run it from within the IDE it may flush the buffer automatically. If I run it in my linux bash shell for example, it waits 5 seconds and then prints all five numbers at once.

Comment: `cout` output is *typically* buffered, but is not *required* to be. The 2 behaviors described by the book are the *typical* behaviors in most implementations, when `cout` is line-buffered, meaning the buffer is not flushed until a line break is printed (or the buffer fills up).  `std::endl` and `std::flush` both force an immediate flush

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of with and without flushing with an exception (which should kill the program before the final line gets flushed):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "test with flush" << std::flush;
    std::cout << "test without flush";
    throw;
}
```

when compiled and ran in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GbaYnovnP) I see:

```
Program returned: 139
terminate called without an active exception
test with flush
```

but no mention of "test without flush", since the program ends before it can be automatically flushed.

Comment: And how does this explain why the OP does not see any difference for code 1 and code2? Based on what the OP says it might be that the environment that is used by the OP might actually show `test without flush`.

Comment: That is true. My thought was using the same godbolt config should result in the same output - the sleeping thing doesn't really work there since it pushes all the output at once